# no reaction to Eventhandler by input type=file in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

following Code works fine for IE, but not for Firefox (version 24.2.0 ESR)...

```
<input type="file" name="datei" id="data" onChange="enable();">

<input type="submit" id="submitConfig" value="Konfiguration abschicken" disabled="true" style="margin-left: 250px;">
```

and the triggered Script...

```
function enable() {

document.getElementById("submitConfig").removeAttribute("disabled");

}
```

is this behaviour of not reacting to EventHandlers (also tried "onClick") a "security-feature" of firefox, or is this a bug? 
And is there a possible cross-browser workaround, to get the submitbutton only enabled if a file is chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Jquery way works fine in all browsers. It is simple:  Removing
>   disabled attr

```
$("#submitConfig").removeAttr('disabled');
```

> Adding disabled attr

```
 $("#submitConfig").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: i have avoided jquery up till now... big mistake by me... worked perfectly fine on the first try
thx for letting me learn something new^^

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
document.getElementById("submitConfig").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

use

```
document.getElementById("submitConfig").disabled = true;
   or
document.getElementById("submitConfig").disabled = false;
```

Comment: thx for the suggestion, but the problem is not the script itself... the problem is that the eventhandler doesn't react to a chosen file in firefox, so the script doesn't even get evoked

Comment: just try checking the alert(1); on onchange event, remove the enable() function